# Simple stored procedure parameter is causing an unknown error

Tags: mysql, sql

It's a simple procedure, I just cannot for the life of me find the error in this syntax. I've learned at other posts and couldn't find a working solution.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cooldownUpdate @command VARCHAR(18)
AS
UPDATE `mention_cooldowns` SET cooldown = 'true' WHERE command = @command
GO;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`@command  VARCHAR(18) AS UPDATE mention_cooldowns SET cooldown = 'true' WHERE c`' at
> line 1

Comment: `@variable` is user-defined variable which cannot be a parameter rather than local variable (without `@` char)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to set a delimiter while creating stored procedure. Also, you have to define whether the parameter is for `IN` or `OUT` and finally you have to wrap your queries inside `BEGIN` and `END` for best practice.

Please check below for creating stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE cooldownUpdate(IN pCommand VARCHAR(18))
BEGIN
    UPDATE `mention_cooldowns` SET cooldown = 'true' WHERE command = pCommand;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The procedure contains only one statement - so BEGIN-END and delimiter re-assign are excess.